# Error 1068: The dependency service or group failed to start (Windows 7)

Tags: web-services, iis

I am trying to start **Internet Information Services**, but I haven't been able to for a few days now. 
Initially I did not see **Internet Information Services** in *Administrative Tools* in *Control Panel*. What I did was, I opened *Add Program*, and I checked the checkbox for **Internet Information Services** in the left pane **Turn Windows features on or off**, which made **Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager** inside *Administrative Tools*.

Now I am trying to *start* it, but it won't. When I click on *Start* button in the right pane under **Manage Web Site**, I get an error message:

> The World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC) is stopped. Web sites cannot be started unless the World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC) is running.

When I googled this error message, almost everyone had said the same thing to fix this:

1. Hit Windows + R keys together
2. Enter `services.msc` and hit Enter
3. Under Services details, scroll down to **World Wide Web Publishing Service**
4. Right click it and *start* it

However, this does not work for me with an error message:

> Windows could not start the World Wide Web Publishing Service service on Local Computer. 
>   Error 1068: The dependency service or group failed to start.

When I looked up this error, the only solution I found was:

1. Right click and go to *Properties* of **World Wide Web Publishing Service**
2. Check all dependencies under *Dependencies* tab

I made sure all the dependencies and those subdependencies are running fine (checked if they are in state of *started*). 
However, I still get the same error, and I am unable to start IIS.

Can someone please tell me what can be other possible causes and solutions to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue, mine was down to having an invalid applicationHost file in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config

Once i had fixed this the W3SVC worked fine

Hope this helps

Comment: What was invalid about it?

Comment: and we will never know....

Answer (score 0):

For me HTTP SSL was stopped and once I started it and Then I restarted WWW Publishing service and done the IIS Reset and Everything worked for me

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem and finally found a different solution worked out.

After resetting IIS it doesn't response to start. We got error message, "Cannot start service W3SVC on computer".

When we try to start the Windows Service World Wide Web Publishing Service W3SVC, we get error , 1068 the dependency service or group failed to start.
After tracing the dependency service tab, we tried to start that service also but got the same error.

Restarting server, un-insalling antivirus and restarting again, but the problem remain same.

Folder C:\inetpub became hidden folder (Don't know how it became hidden).
We have removed the hidden flag after login as Administrator and the problem starting the services and dependable services is resolved. Finally we got the IISRESET successfully executed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the error similar to the above where this was never answered.

I had exactly the same issue, mine was down to having an invalid applicationHost file in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`

In my case I went to the following location `C:\inetpub\history` and copied the `applicationHost` file from there replacing the file in this location `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`

Once this was replaced (backup the existing one first) I was able to start IIS and all of the dependent service started by themselves.